# Magento 2: Unable to resize the swatch image

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, swatches, color-swatches, configurable-swatches

[image]

view.xml:

```
        <image id="swatch_image_base" type="swatch_image">
            <width>500</width>
            <height>600</height>
        </image>

         <image id="swatch_image" type="swatch_image">
            <width>500</width>
            <height>600</height>
        </image>
        <image id="swatch_thumb" type="swatch_thumb">
            <width>500</width>
            <height>600</height>
        </image>
        <image id="swatch_thumb_base" type="swatch_thumb">
            <width>500</width>
            <height>600</height>
        </image>
```

Swatch image is not resizing,it update the size of product image of size 213 x 300 when clicked on any configurable color swatches.

The output:

```
<img class="product-image-photo" src=" 213 x 300 size of image path " max-width="500" max-height="600" >
```

Please help me,if something missed here on view.xml file or any other way to do so.

**Note: Done the cache clear, flushed the images, even deployed the static content.**

Comment: I want to do keep frame false on this. Can I do this in view.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On view.xml added this line

```
        <image id="product_swatch_image_medium" type="image">
            <width>500</width>
            <height>600</height>
        </image>
```